# Swift unit test throwing function from inside a closure

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, firebase, error-handling

I want to create a test for a function with closure that throws an error. What is the best practice to do this test?

Credential.swift

```
class Credential {
    let email: String
    let password: String

    init(email: String, password: String) {
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    }
}
```

SignUpError.swift

```
enum SignUpError: Error {
    case other(error: Error)
    case userAlreadyExist
}
```

FirebaseController.swift

```
typealias SignUpResult = (_ inner: () throws -> RebloodUser) -> Void
func signUp(_ credential: RebloodCredential, completionHandler: @escaping SignUpResult) {
    self.auth.createUser(withEmail: credential.email, password: credential.password) { (user: User?, error: Error?) in

        guard let user = user, error == nil else {
            completionHandler({ () -> RebloodUser in
                throw SignUpError.other(error: error!)
            })
            return
        }


        completionHandler({ () -> RebloodUser in
            let rebloodUser = RebloodUser(firebaseIdentifier: user.uid)
            return rebloodUser
        })

    }
}
```

FirebaseControllerTests.swift

```
let controller = FirebaseController()
let credential = Credential(email: "address@email.com", password: "Password1234")

func testControllerCanSignUp() {
    self.controller.signUp(self.credential) { (inner: () throws -> RebloodUser) -> Void in
        do {
            let user = try inner()
            XCTAssertNotNil(user.firebaseIdentifier)
            return
        } catch SignUpError.userAlreadyExist {
            return
        } catch {
            XCTFail("Wrong error thrown")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCT provides `XCTAssertNoThrow` and `XCTAssertThrowsError` for explicitly asserting the throwing or not-throwing of exceptions (more on that e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@hybridcattt/how-to-test-throwing-code-in-swift-c70a95535ee5)).

For example: `XCTAssertNoThrow(try inner())`

If, however, you are more interested in the result of the expression (as in your case the returned `user`) and *expect* that the call should not throw anyway, you can also ignore these assertion functions and instead use `try?` and any of the "normal" assertions (e.g. `XCTAssertEqual`); the test will still break if an exception is thrown unexpectedly because the expression will evaluate to `nil` in this case and the comparing assertion will fail (unless your test expects `nil` as the correct result, in which case things get more complicated and you'll have to explicitly check that no exception was thrown.) Note that with this code you will not know whether the test failed because of an exception or because the returned value was invalid.

For example: `XCTAssertNotNil(try? inner().firebaseIdentifier)`

**NOTE**: *That said, if you don't mind writing a few lines more, the way you implemented the expection testing is fine as well and is definitely more flexible that the assertion approach.*

---

Another hint for your tests: Assuming that `FirebaseController.auth.createUser` is an asynchronous method, you should use XCT expectations to let the test wait until the callback is called:

```
func testControllerCanSignUp() {
    let exp = expectation(description: "callback called") // create the expectation
    controller.signUp(self.credential) { (inner: () throws -> RebloodUser) -> () in
        XCTAssertNotNil(try? inner().firebaseIdentifier)
        exp.fulfill() // tell the test that your expectation was fulfilled
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 1, handler: nil) // let the test wait for up to one second to give your async code the chance to complete
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dr_barto, that helps!